# how to get document property value in html script

Tags: javascript, html, tibco, spotfire

Is there a way to get document property values into html script in text area.

for example:
 I have a drop down which have values like `"google","yahoo","Facebook"`
and my html script may be like

```
< SpotfireControl id="a23e53a498af447294614ec708f50ede" /> A href="http://www.Document propety value.com/">.
```

So if you select google in drop down ,the above html script will change to

```
< SpotfireControl id="a23e53a498af447294614ec708f50ede" /> A href="http://www.google.com/">
```

I want to see this dropdown and link in one text area.

much appreciated

Comment: Not using HTML solely. HTML is a markup language, not a programming language, so you'll have to use JavaScript for this. I would add the HTML and JS tags to your question to broaden the SO community.

Comment: Thanks scsimon adding js and html tags

Answer (score 2):

If your tag is as follows:

```
<a id="mylink" href="">
```

Then you can set the href like so:

```
document.getElementById("mylink").href = "https://google.com";
```

If your `select` has an `id="myselect"`, you can get the value like so:

```
document.getElementById("myselect").value
```

Now you can set your link:

```
var site = document.getElementById("myselect").value;
document.getElementById("mylink").href = "https://"+site+".com";
```

Now, you want this to happen when you *change* the drop-down (select) option, so you'll need to add an event listener for when it changes.

```
document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("change",
    function() {
        var site = document.getElementById("myselect").value;
        document.getElementById("mylink").href = "https://"+site+".com";
    }
}
```

Do note that your event listener can only be added after the selector and the link have loaded (so the code needs to be afterwards). If you've never used JavaScript before, you should note that you need `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` tags to enclose it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please elaborate this. I am new to java script.
Also why you used two variables (myselect,mylink)?. i have only one variable, which is a drop down having different values like google,yahoo etc. and why +site+ used in href instead of above variable ?

Comment: Hi Julie, the `id="myselect"` is the `id` of a HTML element, e.g. the `select`, or the `a` element with your link. These aren't "variables", just IDs that you use to interface with the HTML structure, via `document.getElementById()`. I did miss off the `var site =` bit, I have now edited that in - the `var site` line takes the value of the `"myselect"` element, then stores it in the variable `site`, which I use in the next line. Hopefully this clarifies it - let me know if there's something I've missed out.